# Coordinates system in Babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

I'm a little confused about the coordinates system in Babylon.js. That is, when I use the following sequence of statements :

```
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 0, 0, 50, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);
    var sphere1 = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere1", 16, 1.0, scene);
```

the sphere is painted in the center of the screen. OK. When I use the following sequence :

```
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("Camera", 50, 0, 0, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);
    var sphere1 = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere1", 16, 1.0, scene);
```

no sphere is painted.

I know that usually the coordinates (in CG) are as follows: Oy - vertical, Ox - horizontal, Oz - pointing to the screen. So, in the second sequence, the camera is in the point x = 50, in the plane xOz (that is ground) and is looking to origin, where the sphere is.

I guess somewhere on the road I was lost. Can you help to understand where I am wrong ?

Thank you,

Eb_cj

Answer (score 1):

Hello ArcRotateCamera uses two angles (alpha and beta) to define the position of the camera on a sphere centered around a point.

Feel free to read this for more info:
https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/wiki/05-Cameras